# Sparx Enterprise Architect, validating class model elements

Tags: validation, xsd, uml, xsd-validation, enterprise-architect

Long time reader, first time questioner.

I'm using enterprise architect to create class models, which I'm then going to transform into XSD. But my question is, I want to check the elements in the class model against an approved list (Lookup?) to wheedle out any errors before I create the XSD.

Can anybody give me some options, I've looked at the validation, but it doesn't offer me the chance to upload my own file to validate against.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

D

Comment: What do you want to validate? XSD?

Comment: Well, ideally, i'd like to validate the class model elements against an approved list to check for name errors before I create the XSD.

Comment: What do you mean by "name errors"? UML does not really have a naming convention. They come from processes being applied and need to be implemented individually.

Comment: The Class Models we are building are populated from a list of data elements that are published internally, as these are sometimes copied and pasted or manually entered, errors have been found in previous iterations and blank spaces. I need to be able to validate the class model against the internal list which I can import in possibly a .csv format, which will pick up the manual entry errors. Thanks

Comment: Does anyone else have any answrs, as i wasnt given a proper one?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367893/the-most-heartbreaking-question-the-eager-but-hopeless?cb=1

Comment: Anybody have anything useful for me that isnt an ancedote? i am new to EA and would appreciate a straight forward anser that doesnt involve coding.

Comment: What do you expect? A magic spell? I told you it's only possible with coding involved. So either get yourself someone doing the job for you or stop whining, please. Sincerely, The Angry Child.

Comment: Hi Thomas, not a problem. Ive since spoken to a couple of people on the Sparx board who have given me a couple of none programming ways of doing what I need. TTFN D